# how to make fixed column and a varying row into varying for both?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to clear contents on row and columns when there is a 0 found.

I'm able to write out a code to clear them, but I can only vary the row. My column is fixed and it starts to get a little lengthy after i add in more of similar codes to consider columns A to Z.

My codes is as follows

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim columnval As Long, k As Long

For k = 5 To 6

    If (Range("A" & k)) = 0 Then
    Range("A" & k).ClearContents
    End If

Next k

For k = 5 To 6

    If (Range("B" & k)) = 0 Then
    Range("B" & k).ClearContents
    End If

Next k

End Sub
```

The code is working, just that it gets too lengthy when comes to column Z. If you have a better way, do share it with me! Thanks!

Comment: When you are searching for a value then Looping through columns and rows in an inefficient way to achieve your goal. Updated a code sample for you below. More can be read here (http://siddharthrout.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the **shortest** and the **fastest** way to achieve what you want.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Replace What:="0", Replacement:="", _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

**FOLLOW UP**

> > > Hi, what if i only wants to clear content over at row 5 and 6, column A-Z? It seems like it is clearing everything. – user1204868 14 mins ago

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim Rng As Range

    Set Rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A5:" & "Z" & Rows.Count)

    Rng.Replace What:="0", Replacement:="", _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

Sid

Comment: Hi sid, thank you for you answer again! :) I have tried yours, but it somehow remove all the rows below row 5. Its ok. I shall use Jerry's answer! :)

Comment: Yes because we are telling it to... Which rows do you want to remove? If you want to clear only rows 5 and 6 then replace {"Z" & Rows.Count} by "Z6" ;)

Answer (score 1):

This approach will shrink down the number of cells evaluated to just the rows and columns you've used, no more.  Should be pretty fast:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ClearZeroValuesInUsedRange()
Dim LR As Long, LC As Long, r As Long, c As Long

LR = Cells.Find("*", Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
LC = Cells.Find("*", Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count), SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For r = 1 To LR
        For c = 1 To LC
            If Cells(r, c) = 0 Then Cells(r, c).ClearContents
        Next c
    Next r

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

And you can vary the starting number if you want to skip some rows at the top or columns on the left by increasing the **1** to some higher number.

This example is for Rows 5 & 6 A-Z only:

```
Sub ClearZeroValuesInUsedRange()
Dim r As Long, c As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For r = 5 To 6
        For c = 1 To 26
            If Cells(r, c) = 0 Then Cells(r, c).ClearContents
        Next c
    Next r

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, what if i only wants to clear content over at row 5 and 6, column A-Z? It seems like it is clearing everything.

Comment: Yes it was, i've added the second version above that just does those rows/columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
option explicit

sub conditional_clear()
    dim r as long
    dim c as long
    dim ws as worksheet

    for each ws in worksheets
        for r = 1 to ws.usedrange.rows.count
            for c = 1 to ws.usedrange.columns.count
                with ws.cells(r,c)
                    if .value = 0 then 
                        .clearcontents
                    end if 
                end with 
            next c
        next r
    next ws
end sub
```

Edit:
If you want more control over the area in which you clear cell contents, change to something like this

```
sub conditional_clear(srow as long, erow as long, scol as long, ecol as long)
    ...
        for r = srow to erow
            for c = scol to ecol
    ...
```

and call it like this

```
call conditional_clear(5, 6, 1, 26)
```

Comment: hi, it seems like there is an error in your code, over at .clearcontents()

Comment: hi, that was a test. you passed.